# Answering large homework style questions

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a question (now deleted) which basically took a section of homework style questions and copy pasted them into the question. While I understand that we are all here to help people learn the grammar concerned with English and explain some small differences in words and word order, the questions given here could have been answered with a dictionary.

What are the procedures to be taken with this? I would be happy to assist with the explanation of a complicated sentence or hard to understand grammatical structure. I would be less willing to, in essence, do someone's homework for them.

Comment: Related: [Policy on homework questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1151/9161),  [Are there policies for test questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/3106/9161)

Comment: IIRC, once upon a time, I tried to get meta to write a policy on homework, but as usual, I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is essentially copy-pasting the exam text, without describing the doubts the OP have, or what the OP doesn't understand, the question should be closed. We even have a closing reason that suits that case.

> This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context.

A homework question where the OP doesn't show any effort in answer it is not much different from another questions where the OP doesn't seem to have put any effort to answer it.

Otherwise, the fact the users are asking a question about homework they have should not be so relevant for us to answer it.